# Using remove and then erase to delete elements of container

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing this as I am very confused. Am I dreaming or have I always been wrong to what `remove` does?

Suppose we have a vector of integers:

`std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1}`

We want to remove all the number 1 from the vector so:

`auto it {std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 1)};`

Now our container will look like this:
`2 3 4 1 1 1` with the iterator `it` pointing on index 3

After that we use this:

`v.erase(it, v.end());` to remove all the elements from the iterator to the end of the vector, corresponding to all the 1s. Isnt this how you remove the elements or am I delusional?

What I was surprised about is that we dont need to add erase. Remove will remove all elements. My professor told me to use erase from the iterator to the end of the vector to delete all the elements after performing remove.

Comment: `std::remove` doesn't actually remove any elements from a container, all it does it reorder elements in such a way, that the elements that are equal to the argument will be placed at the end.

Comment: *What I was surprised about is that we dont need to add erase. Remove will remove all elements* What do you mean by that?  You said after you call remove, the container looks like `2 3 4 1 1 1` which doesn't look like anything was removed to me.

Comment: Iterators cannot be used to directly add or remove elements. Only the container itself can do that. Algorithms like `std::remove` that work strictly with iterators are never capable of performing an operation that would change the size of the container. The best they can do is to do as much as possible and to make it as easy as possible for the container to finish what they couldn't do. `std::remove` puts everything before its return value in the correct state it should be if those elements had been removed, but to actually reduce the number of elements you need to ask the container to `erase`

Comment: @Kaldrr Not quite right. It only ensures that the elements that are **not equal** will be at the beginning. For OP's code, I get elements of `2 3 4 1 4 1` after the call to `remove`. The elements left over at the end are in an ***unspecified state***.

Comment: @AdrianMole What is an unspecified state?

Comment: In your case, where the elements are simple integers, it just means that the *values* of those elements could be anything at all (i.e. unspecified). If the vector elements were more complex class types, then they may or may not even be in a valid, readable state.

Answer (score 1):

> Isnt this how you remove the elements

Yes, remove and erase are used as you described in paragraphs preceding the last one.

> Now our container will look like this: 2 3 4 1 1 1

Not quite. The container will look like this: 2 3 4 X X X. Where values X are unspecified. The algorithm doesn't need to bother overwriting the elements in the "removed" partition.

> What I was surprised about is that we dont need to add erase.

You don't need to erase if it's fine for the residual elements to remain in the vector. If you do need to erase the elements, you can achieve that by erasing them.

> Remove will remove all elements.

As per your earlier description, remove will only move the non-removed elements to the left partition. It will not erase any elements from the container. The size of the container won't change.

---

P.S. instead of remove-erase idiom, you can use `std::erase`:

```
std::erase(v, 1);
```

Comment: Note that `std::erase` requires C++20 or later.